# Abbreviations in Bus Schedules

Tags: значения, сокращения

I found the following two expressions in a bus schedule:

> Время отправления с НП

> Время прибытия на КП

I understand that the first one means "time of departure" and the second "time of arrival", but what do "с НП" and "на КП" stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, these abbreviations stand for:

- НП - начальный пункт (starting point/stop)
- КП - конечный пункт (ending point/stop)

Hence the two lines are:

> Время отправления с НП
> (Time of departure from the starting point)

> Время прибытия на КП
> (Time of arrival at the destination/ending point)

Comment: @Quassnoi I don't understand what you mean when you say "That's not how it works in Russian".

Comment: I think he means that in Russian, they actually use the abbreviations and don't write these words out.

Comment: @ElementsInSpace: the first expanded abbreviation should have been put into the instrumental case. However, the author elected not to expand them so neither should we.